# GPUImage: Apply filter to a portion of the input

Tags: opengl-es, gpuimage

I'm new to OpenGL and GPUImage, so that I'm not sure whether this is an OpenGL or a GPUImage question.

I've written a fragment shader that separates the input into its color components, by applying a color offset to output color.

```
NSString *const kRGBShiftShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 uniform highp vec2 redOffset;
 uniform highp vec2 greenOffset;
 uniform highp vec2 blueOffset;

 void main()
 {
     highp vec4 textureColor      = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

     highp vec4 redOffsetColor    = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + redOffset);
     highp vec4 greenOffsetColor  = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + greenOffset);
     highp vec4 blueOffsetColor   = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate + blueOffset);

     highp vec4 outputColor;

     outputColor.r         = redOffsetColor.r;
     outputColor.g         = greenOffsetColor.g;
     outputColor.b         = blueOffsetColor.b;
     outputColor.a         = 1.0;

     gl_FragColor = outputColor;

 }
);
```

This is works just as I intend, except for the case where `textureCoordinate + offset` is > 1   or < 0 in one or more of its components. In that case the color clamps to whatever color is at the edge of the input texture.

What I would like to have happen is that filter has no effect when textureCoordinate + offset is > 1 or >0.

I think it would be quite stupid to do this by putting a conditional into the shader. Instead, I would rather just tell GPUImage that the filter only applies to fragments where textureCoordinate + offset is in [0, 1]. How would I do that?

Comment: Does applying the filter outside of your range produce undesirable visual artifacts, or are you only worried about performance?

Comment: By the way. You might be able to get a performance boost by calculating those texture coordinates in the vertex shader and using the interpolated value in the fragment shader. This gives the gpu a chance to pre-fetch the texture samples.

Comment: Yes, it produce an undesirable look. Whenever I sample any coordinate component greater than 1.0 or less than 0, it gives me the sample at 1 or 0, respectively. This causes streaking.

Thanks for the tip about the vertex shader. I'll look into that.